# How do I recover my missing 'src' folder for one of my project

Tags: android, android-manifest

Quite surprising I have recently updated one of my android app and now when I try to open it, it says:

```
Cannot read packageName from D:\Dell_Data\Data\Android_Projects\GK Quiz\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Neither do the explorer window shows me 'src' folder.

[image: windows_explorer]

**Note:** I haven't deleted anything, and nothing is hidden. This is the first time I'm facing such a weird issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Probably there was a problem with your updating. What do you mean by updating? pulling?

Comment: It doesn't make sense at all, the only way this can happening is if you have moved or delete the folder. Try searching some methods you used in the project and see if your computer get a file somewhere.

Comment: @HB None of this makes sense to me either. Looks like I'm screwed big time. My biggest worry is to re-create Sqlite db. :( Even VCS history is not pulling anything.

Comment: The only logical explanation is that it's moved or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

if there is no long time , you can open the android studio and right click on the place that that deleted files where , then local history and you will find the deleted files in gray color , then you can get it again